# how to style and customize the rails date time select field?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, format

i am having a datetime field in my table, in user view to select the date time i am using datetime_select view helper. i want to style this with bootstrap classes and i don't want the default date format that it is showing. how can i format this date time select and how can i style this field?

this is the code i am using now.

```
 <%= f.datetime_select :check_out_req , ampm: true , :class => "form-control"%>
```

it's displaying datetime select drop downs in the format `year,month, date,hours, minutes`. but i want it to display the dropdowns in the format `day,month,year,hours,minutes` .

and when i apply styling like this `:class => "form-control"` the styling is not applyig. how to style this field?

Answer (score 6):

The [datetime_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select) method has two hashes, one for `options` and one for `html_options`. You need to tell Ruby explicitly which keys belong to which hash. Since `ampm` belongs in the `options` hash and `class` belongs in the `html_options` hash, you need to separate the hashes. In addition, if you want to re-order the drop downs, provide the `order` option:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :check_out_req, { ampm: true, order: [:day, :month, :year] }, { class: "form-control" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily insert your `datetime` select field inside a `span` element and assign a **CSS** class to it. Take this snippet as an example;

**HTML:**

```
<span class="datetime"><%= f.datetime_select :check_out_req , ampm: true , :class => "form-control"%><span/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.datetime select:nth-child(1) {
  width: 130px;
  text-indent: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order by passing order parameter.

example:

date_select("article", "written_on", order: [:day, :month, :year])

for more detail please refer the the link:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select